# String matching in iOS returning 0x00000001?

Tags: ios, objective-c, if-statement

i have a simple string checking code, which will check NSString which coming from my server to the NSString which i hard coded in my xcode.

Please check the code

```
if([[array valueForKey:@"type"] isEqualToString:@"type"]  ) {
//Failed
}
```

input values are these

```
[array valueForKey:@"type"] is a string from server  'type'
```

When i did this in xcode console

```
po [[array valueForKey:@"type"] isEqualToString:@"type"]
```

i got output as

```
0x00000001
```

Both strings are same but then what is this 0x00000001??

Comment: That is a `BOOL` returnig `1`. @Naveen That means your condition is true.

Comment: but it didnt went inside

Comment: `po` is "print object". Use `p` instead for scalar values.

Comment: Is `array` an  array or a dictionary? Do you intentionally use the Key-Value coding method `valueForKey` ?

Comment: @NaveenKumarP : Can you show the structure of your `array`?

Comment: print your `array`

Comment: Why u use po? just use NSLog. zz

Answer (score 0):

What are you doing now in printing the result of the comparison, to check the value of string you have to print [array valueForKey:@"type"] value alone, or print value of the all items of the array just to be sure.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

`[array valueForKey:@"type"]` is going to return a value most likely different than a string. Assuming array is a **NSDictionary** filled with **NSIntegers** then the integer for key **"type"** is not going to be equal to the string **"type"**.

Answer (score 0):

I thought you got a hexadecimal value. All hexadecimal values start from `0x`. You got value equals to `1`. In if statement 1 equals to true. So your compared strings are equal. This `0x0000000000000001` value comes from a compiler and that way compiler designed.

Answer (score -1):

Here, [array valueForKey:@"type"]

array must be NSDictionary... because array don't have "valueForKey:" method..

Better you first save in some var and then do comparison.